# Copying base environment to create a new environment in Python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I'm working with some new libraries and I'm afraid that my script might show some troubles in the future with unexpected updates of packages. So I want to create a new environment but I don't want to manually install all the basic packages like numpy, pandas, etc. So, does it makes sense to create a new environment using conda which is the exact copy of my base environment or could it create some sort of conflict?

Comment: No, the environments are completely separated, there will be no conflicts.

Comment: ok thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Copying using conda works, but if you used only virtualenv, you should manually build requirements.txt, create a new virtual environment, activate it, and then simply use `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Note the key word - `manually`.

For example if you needed `requests`, `numpy` and pandas, your `requirements.txt` would look like this:

```
requests==2.20.0
numpy==1.15.2
pandas==0.23.4
```

You could actually exclude numpy in this case, but you still keep it as you are using it and if you removed pandas you'd still need it. I build it by installing a new package and then using pip freeze to find the module I just installed and put it into the requirements.txt with current version. Of course if I ever get to the state where I will share it with someone, I replace `==` with `>=`, most of the time that's enough, if it conflicts, you need to check what the conflicting library requires, and adjust if possible, e.g. you put in latest numpy version as requirement, but older library needs specifically x.y.z version and your library is perfectly fine with that version too (ideal case).

Anyway, this is how much you have to keep around to preserve your virtual environment, also helps if you are going to distribute your project, as anyone can drop this file into a new folder with your source and create their own environment without any hassle.

Now, this is why you should build it manually:

```
$ pip freeze
certifi==2018.10.15
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.7
numpy==1.15.2
pandas==0.23.4
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.20.0
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.24
virtualenv==16.0.0
```

`six`? `pytz`? *What?* Other libraries use them but we don't even know what they are for unless we look it up, and they shouldn't be listed as project dependencies, they will be installed if they depend on it.

This way you ensure that there won't be too many problems only in *very rare cases* where one library you are using needs a new version of another library but the other library wants an ancient version of the library of which the version is conflicting and in that case it's a big mess, but normally it doesn't happen.